# ClassNotFoundException for com.squareup.okhttp.internal.framed.IncomingStreamHandler

Tags: android, unit-testing, rx-java, rx-android, retrofit2

I am writing unit test cases for a class which uses Reactive programming and Retrofit. I am getting the following exception:

```
com.locationlabs.finder.android.core.manager.AuthManagerTest > logout_ok STANDARD_ERROR
    Jan 07, 2016 11:28:06 PM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 execute
    INFO: MockWebServer[51867] starting to accept connections
    Jan 07, 2016 11:28:07 PM com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 execute
    WARNING: MockWebServer[51867] failed unexpectedly
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/squareup/okhttp/internal/framed/IncomingStreamHandler
        at com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer.serveConnection(MockWebServer.java:414)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer.access$800(MockWebServer.java:93)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3.acceptConnections(MockWebServer.java:389)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3.execute(MockWebServer.java:356)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:33)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.squareup.okhttp.internal.framed.IncomingStreamHandler
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        ... 8 more
```

Here is my Retrofit class and the Manager class.

```
import java.util.Map;

import retrofit.http.Body;
import retrofit.http.Headers;
import retrofit.http.POST;
import rx.Observable;

public interface AuthService {
   @POST("auth/endAuthSession")
   @Headers({"Content-Type: application/json"})
   Observable<Void> logout();
}

public class AuthManager {
   private AuthService authService;
    public AuthManager(AuthService authService) {
      this.authService = authService;
   }

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Map;

import rx.Observable;
import rx.functions.Func1;

public Observable<Void> logout() {
    return authService.logout()
            .map(new Func1<Void, Void>() {
               @Override
               public Void call(Void nothing) {
                  JsonUtil.token = null;
                  return null;
               }
            });
   }
}
```

And following is my unit test case:

```
import com.ll.core.manager.AuthManager;
import com.ll.core.service.AuthService;
import retrofit.GsonConverterFactory;
import rx.Subscriber;
import rx.observers.TestSubscriber;

import junit.framework.Assert;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockResponse;
import com.squareup.okhttp.mockwebserver.MockWebServer;
import com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import retrofit.JacksonConverterFactory;
import retrofit.Retrofit;
import retrofit.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.Override;
import java.lang.Throwable;
import java.lang.Void;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;


/**
 * Unit test case for AuthManager.
 */
public class AuthManagerTest {
    private AuthService authService;
    private MockWebServer server;
    private Gson gson;

    @Before
    public void setup() throws IOException {
        server = new MockWebServer();
        server.start();
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit
                .Builder()
                .baseUrl(server.url("/"))
                .addConverterFactory(JacksonConverterFactory.create())
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
                .client(new OkHttpClient())
                .build();

        authService = retrofit.create(AuthService.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void logout_ok(){
        //Setup resonse.
        MockResponse response = new MockResponse()
                .setResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK);
        server.enqueue(response);
        AuthManager authManager = new AuthManager(authService);
        TestSubscriber sub = new TestSubscriber();
        authManager.logout().subscribe(sub);
        sub.assertCompleted();
    }
}
```

Initially googling indicated that `okio` library should be included. I still run into same exception even after including `okio, library. Here is my gradle file.

```
dependencies {
   compile group: 'com.google.android.gms', name: 'play-services-analytics', version: '8.4.0'

   // HTTP libs
   compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta2'
   compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.1'
   compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:logging-interceptor:2.6.0'

   // Reactive libs
   compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.1.0'
   compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.0'
   compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:adapter-rxjava:2.0.0-beta2'

   // JSON libs
   compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.7.0-rc2'
   compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.7.0-rc2'
   compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-jackson:2.0.0-beta2'

   // DI libs
   compile group: 'com.google.dagger', name: 'dagger', version: '2.0.2'
   apt group: 'com.google.dagger', name: 'dagger-compiler', version: '2.0.2'
   provided 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'

   // DB lib
   compile 'io.realm:realm-android:0.87.1'

   // Unit testing dependencies
   testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
   testCompile 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.6.0'
   testCompile 'com.squareup.okhttp:mockwebserver:2.5.0'
   testCompile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit-mock:2.0.0-beta2'
   testCompile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta2'
}
```

**EDIT1**:

When I run the following command:

`jar -tvf ~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.squareup.okhttp/okhttp/2.5.0/4de2b4ed3445c37ec1720a7d214712e845a24636/okhttp-2.5.0.jar`

I do see the class in the jar.

```
  995 Tue Aug 25 21:12:54 PDT 2015 com/squareup/okhttp/internal/framed/IncomingStreamHandler$1.class
   593 Tue Aug 25 21:12:54 PDT 2015 com/squareup/okhttp/internal/framed/IncomingStreamHandler.class
```

I am still confuse why unit test is not able to find this class even though it is in the jar file. It looks like it is Jar hell problem.

**EDIT2**:
It was indeed the Jar hell problem.
If you notice the above gradle file I am using 2.7.1 version for `okhttp` but using 2.5.0 version for `mockwebser`. The problem was fixed when I used `2.7.1` version of mockwebserver.

Comment: You're using okhttp 2.7.1 and mockwebserver 2.5.0. I don't reckon they're compatible. Use version 2.7.1 for both.

Comment: you are little late but thanks tough. Even I observed the same issue and fixed it by using the same version for mockwebserver.

Answer (score 0):

While obfuscating your code with proguard, you need to add exception to avoid classes, methods or fields from proguard. Most of your libraries are in danger zone cause of reflection. You need to find spesific proguard config for each library that use for example RXJava, Dagger, Retrofit and GSON.

Another solution forget the proguard or go safe like avoid whole retrofit package.